# ::after pseudo-element not appearing on Chrome Mobile

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, web

Pretty simple but odd bug, I have a pseudo-element which is appearing fine on desktop browsers but disappears on mobile Chrome (not sure about iOS, no iPhone to test with)

Here's the basic CSS:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  overflow: visible;
}

a::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 8px;
  width: 98%;
  background: #8BC8F690;
  margin-top: -9px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<a>hello</a>
```

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/w4d1jteb/

Comment: You can debug your code using chrome remote debug, https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/remote-debugging/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your `background`. This is not a valid value. It's 8 chars long, but only can have 6.

```
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  overflow: visible;
}

a::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 8px;
  width: 98%;
  background: #8BC8F690; <-- This is not valid. *1*2
  margin-top: -9px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}
```

*1: You could try `background-color: rgba(139, 200, 246, 0.565)` instead.

*2: Or just use `#8BC8F6`.

See these examples below:

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  overflow: visible;
}

a::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 8px;
  width: 98%;
  background-color: rgba(139, 200, 246, 0.565);
  margin-top: -9px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}

#test {
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  color: #000;
  overflow: visible;
}

#test::after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  height: 8px;
  width: 98%;
  background: #8BC8F6;
  margin-top: -9px;
  margin-left: 2px;
}
```

```html
<a>hello</a>

<a id="test">hello2</a>
```

Comment: correct, and here is a screenshot when I debug the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWJO1.png

Comment: Oh, thanks! Totally forgot I was winging trying alpha values but didn't actually look it up. My bad.